# Acknowledgements outside of document environment

Tags: environments, acknowledgements

How do I add an acknowledgements section (maybe not specifically `\section`) outside of (before) my `document` environment?

in my .cls, there is

```
\def\@acknowledge{}
...
\def\acknowledge#1{\booltrue{@ack} \gdef\@acknowledge{#1}}
...
\def\ackpage{
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\@acknowledge
\newpage
}
```

but it seems that I find problems when I put newlines in the 
`\acknowledge{folks in here}`

(see https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/virginia-tech-etd-template/cpqhbscstfrx )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `\def` the default behaviour of TeX is to *not* allow paragraph breaks, as a mechanism to check for missing braces or other errors in the code.

You have a few options:

If you can modify the `.cls` you can make TeX allow paragraph breaks by making `\acknowledge` a `\long` macro:

```
\long\def\acknowledge#1{\booltrue{@ack}\gdef\@acknowledge{#1}}
```

then it will allow a `\par` token in the argument.

Or you can use LaTeX syntax and use `\newcommand` which, by default, allows paragraph breaks:

```
\newcommand{\acknowledge}[1]{\booltrue{@ack}\gdef\@acknowledge{#1}}
```

Or, if you prefer, you can use the `environ` package and make `acknowledge` look more like an environment:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{acknowledge}{%
  \booltrue{@ack}%
  \global\let\@acknowledge\BODY}
```

the `environ` package stores the contents of the environment in `\BODY`, then you just have to copy it to `\@acknowledge` with `\let`. This allows paragraph breaks by default.

---

If you *cannot* change the `.cls`, then you can bypass TeX's check and use `\endgraf` instead of `\par` or a new line. For example, if you had:

```
\acknowledge{%
  folks in

  here}
```

(which is the same as `\acknowledge{folks in \par here}`) you can use:

```
\acknowledge{folks in\endgraf here}
```

then TeX will not know there is a paragraph break there.

Comment: What a comprehensive answer. Thanks so much!